# Highchart - Redraw Chart after Window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

on my webpage is a chart drawn with Highchart. 
Now, if i resize my whole window i want this chart to adjusts its size (especially the width). The Code looks similar to this:

```
window.onresize=function(){resized();}

function resized()
{
   $("#container").highcharts().redraw();
}
```

If I overwrite the redraw event (with something like "alert("resized");") I will get a result so the method should be called - but the chart doesn't changes its size.
I also tried to set the charts size manually with

```
$("#container").highcharts().setSize(width, height, false);
```

But both ways didn't work. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Why did you set redraw=false in setSize? If you won't redraw chart after setSize then you won't see effect.. Anyway, jsFiddle demo would be great. In general, it should just work.

Comment: Well, yeah.. this solved my problem.. really embarassing :) Thanks

Comment: After reading http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize it's not important* if the 3rd parameter is true or false.  *(just for perfomance reasons)

Comment: Well, if you will create demo with that issue, I will check this out :)

Comment: @PawełFus: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/2632/

Comment: Okay, but where is the problem? I'm not sure.. see: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/2633/

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood your demo request, but with a plenty more data the resizing seems a little bit slow if you set the 3rd param to 'true' in setSize. But the original problem is solved, so i think we can leave it here.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try code in this manner so it will automatically handle chart resizing on window resize.

```
 // create the chart
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    events: {
        redraw: function () {
            var label = this.renderer.label('The chart was just redrawn', 100, 120)
                .attr({
                    fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                    padding: 10,
                    r: 5,
                    zIndex: 8
                })
                .css({
                    color: '#FFFFFF'
                })
                .add();

            setTimeout(function () {
                label.fadeOut();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but my question is 4 years old - so I can't remember my initial problem properly. Even tho your answer might help other people.